How to Address Overfitting in Prophet Model for Sales Forecasting?
I am using Prophet for sales forecasting, but I am encountering an overfitting issue. My current model parameters are leading to an R-squared (R2) value of 1.00, indicating perfect fit, which suggests overfitting. When I try to reduce the changepoint_prior_scale (CPS) and fourier_order values to mitigate this, my error metrics (MAE, MSE, RMSE) increase significantly, leading to very large errors.
Here is my code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from prophet import Prophet
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score, mean_absolute_error

# Load the dataset
file_path = 'data.csv'
sales_df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

# Convert 'tahun' and 'bulan' columns to a datetime object named 'date'
sales_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(sales_df[['tahun', 'bulan']].astype(str).apply('-'.join, axis=1) + '-01')

# Aggregate the data monthly by summing up 'amaun_rm'
sales_df = sales_df.groupby('date')[['amaun_rm']].sum().reset_index()

# Create a date range with all months from the minimum to maximum date
all_months = pd.date_range(start=sales_df['date'].min(), end=sales_df['date'].max(), freq='MS')

# Merge the original data with the complete date range to identify missing months
all_months_df = pd.DataFrame(all_months, columns=['date'])
sales_df = pd.merge(all_months_df, sales_df, on='date', how='left')

# Impute missing 'amaun_rm' values with the mean value
sales_df['amaun_rm'] = SimpleImputer(strategy='mean').fit_transform(sales_df[['amaun_rm']])

# Convert the date components into a datetime object
sales_df = sales_df.rename(columns={'date': 'ds', 'amaun_rm': 'y'})

# Initialize and fit the Prophet model
cps_value = 0.1  # Controls trend flexibility
model = Prophet(changepoint_prior_scale=cps_value,
                daily_seasonality=False,   # Disable daily seasonality
                weekly_seasonality=False,  # Disable weekly seasonality
                yearly_seasonality=True)   # Enable yearly seasonality
model.add_country_holidays(country_name='MY') 
model.add_seasonality("cycle1", 12*30, 13, mode="multiplicative")  # Custom seasonality

model.fit(sales_df)

# Make future predictions for the next 12 months
future = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=36, freq='MS')
forecast = model.predict(future)
forecast['yhat'] = forecast['yhat'].clip(lower=0)

# Merge actual data and forecast data for comparison
merged_data = pd.merge(sales_df, forecast[['ds', 'yhat']], on='ds', how='outer')

# Format the forecast sales to two decimal places
merged_data['yhat'] = merged_data['yhat'].round(2)

# Calculate error metrics to evaluate model performance
mask = ~merged_data['yhat'].isna() & ~merged_data['y'].isna()
y_true = merged_data.loc[mask, 'y']
y_pred = merged_data.loc[mask, 'yhat']

mae = mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
rmse = np.sqrt(mse)
r2 = r2_score(y_true, y_pred)

Output:
Mean Absolute Error (MAE): 71.46
Mean Squared Error (MSE): 10427.38
Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE): 102.11
R-squared (R2): 1.00

Issue:
The R-squared (R2) value is 1.00, indicating perfect fit and overfitting. When I reduce the changepoint_prior_scale (CPS) and fourier_order, the error metrics (MAE, MSE, RMSE) increase dramatically, leading to errors in the range of five to six figures.
Questions:
How can I adjust the changepoint_prior_scale and fourier_order parameters to reduce overfitting while maintaining reasonable error metrics?
What are some best practices for tuning these parameters in Prophet to avoid overfitting?
Are there additional techniques or considerations I should take into account when dealing with overfitting in time series forecasting with Prophet?
Any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
